# how to check the distribution of labels in a PyTorch Dataset subset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to see the distribution of each label in a subset that I split off from the main dataset using the

```
torch.utils.data.random_split()
```

function which returns a subset but I have no clue on how to go about doing that

I have tried using

```
print(dict(Counter(dataset.targets)))
```

but I get an error from it saying that the subset does not have an attribute 'target'

does anyone know how i can go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the exact same problem. A way I've found the distribution of labels is through iterating though the whole dataset:

```
from collections import defaultdict

label_counter = defaultdict(int)

for feature, label in dataset:
    label_counter[label] += 1
```